# Why contextual voice commands in Google Glass limited?

Tags: google-glass

I support a few contextual voice commands in my Glass application. These commands work as expected. However, it appears I can use my custom commands only in development mode. For release mode, one is expected to use commands listed under ContextualMenus.Command. I am confused on why this limitation has been placed and if there is a workaround. My commands are highly specific to my application. I would imagine Google cannot possibly pre-define all possible commands that third-party applications would ever use.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the voice commands are limited seems to be in order to ensure a certain level of quality across all commands. You can try and get your custom voice commands approved [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form).